# SharePoint FullTextSqlQuery Search FREETEXT with multiple columns

Tags: sharepoint, full-text-search

I have a custom `FullTextSqlQuery` used to retrieve some specific pages.
The query contains multiples `FREETEXT` predicates and gives unusable rankings, which is expected behavior according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms516214%28v=office.12%29.aspx), the query should contain only one `FREETEXT`

The basic query that gives expected results is

`SELECT Title, ACLanguage, ACContent, ACCategory, ACKeywords, ACID
FROM scope() 
WHERE (FREETEXT(Title,'text') OR FREETEXT(ACContent, 'text') OR FREETEXT(ACSubtitle, 'text'))`

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms499212.aspx) says this query can be rewritten to use a single predicate using a group alias, but it isn't clear about syntax. I tried multiple statements ending with :

`SELECT Title, ACLanguage, ACContent, ACCategory, ACKeywords, ACID 
FROM scope() 
WHERE WITH(Title, ACSubtitle, ACContent) AS #SearchColumns FREETEXT(#SearchColumns,'text')`

But all my attemps ended with a `QueryMalformedException`

How should this query be written ?

Comment: Have you tried adding quotes around each column name in the WITH statement? See the example [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=PoYgYnodWKkC&pg=PA452&lpg=PA452&dq=sharepoint+sql+%22Group+Alias+Predicate%22&source=bl&ots=RGOwFi81TG&sig=oqsjt0dvlJDNetMgLUAatOn_u_U&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YQd-U_K1K8TNsQS0qILQBg&ved=0CF0Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=sharepoint%20sql%20%22Group%20Alias%20Predicate%22&f=false).

Comment: Yes, i tried with single/double quotes, also with the optional weight like [here](http://books.google.lu/books?id=jU_eS5V5mvwC&pg=PA141&lpg=PA141&dq=%22scope+where+with%22&source=bl&ots=k2eluORplK&sig=UImV0ryFd9sqLW9lfL-xZvxyFo0&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=4xR-U_z3IabS4QSB5YGwAQ&ved=0CGAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22scope%20where%20with%22&f=false), always ends with a `QueryMalformedException`. Just declaring the group with the `WITH .. AS` clause without using it in the `FREETEXT` fails.

Comment: Weird. The documentation for FREETEXT in SharePoint is sorely lacking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify multiple columns like this:

```
SELECT Title, ACLanguage, ACContent, ACCategory, ACKeywords, ACID
FROM scope() 
WHERE (FREETEXT((Title,ACContent,ACSubtitle),'text'))
```

Or, shorthand for searching all full text indexed columns:

```
SELECT Title, ACLanguage, ACContent, ACCategory, ACKeywords, ACID
FROM scope() 
WHERE (FREETEXT(*,'text'))
```

([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx))

Comment: This is a valid T-SQL query, but the [SharePoint Search FREETEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms516214%28v=office.14%29.aspx) seems different and doesn't accept a column list and the query still fails, the query should use a [column group alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms499212.aspx).
The option of using a `*` is not optimal since it includes all columns, but it is the only that seems to work.

Comment: A _different_ FREETEXT syntax for SharePoint? Cursed Microsoft!